# Query Prometheus series where label values/selectors exist in a different query

Tags: prometheus, promql

**Problem:**

I have two separate metrics - one that yields the CPU usage per Kubernetes node and another that tells what Kubernetes node a pod is running on:

Node CPU usage:

```
node_cpu_seconds_total{container="node-exporter",cpu="0",endpoint="http-metrics",instance="10.254.103.112:9100",job="node-exporter",mode="iowait",namespace="monitoring",pod="prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter-r4ts7",provider="aws",service="prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter"}
```

Pod information:

```
kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total{container="foo",endpoint="http",instance="10.254.6.215:8080",job="kube-state-metrics",namespace="proxy",pod="foo-6cbfdbcb-544dv",provider="aws",service="prometheus-kube-state-metrics",uid="a041953a-36b2-43ec-8f81-1fcfac95f33d"}
```

Both metrics have the `instance` label which is the Node's ip address. I want to create a Grafana panel that shows the Node CPU usage, but only for those nodes that run my container. Therfore, I want to match on the `instance` label between both queries and therefore ignore all metrics where not both queries yield the same `instance` at least once.

**Question:**

How can I ignore all results where the same `instance` value is not yielded by both queries?

I tried the following query which yields zero results:

```
node_cpu_seconds_total{mode!="idle"} and on (instance) (kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total{pod=~"foo-.*"})
```

Comment: Your attempt looks correct. What problem do you have with it?

Comment: This query doesn't yield any data at all

Comment: If both parts of said `and` produces some data, and returned data has the same value of `instance` - it should. Please notice, that metrics in your question don't have the same `instance`.

Comment: Thanks @markalex, you are right the instances just don't match, thanks for spending the time on this!